# SWF link on CD

Tags: flash

I have a swf based website. In the main swf I have links to other swf files. If I want this to run from a cd how do link to the files in the root directory of various CD drives. Insetead on a URL my link will have to point to the root directory of the CD. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [specify a different base URL](http://www.yswfblog.com/blog/2008/08/11/all-your-base-are-belong-to-us/).